# Facebook login php sdk - problem on mobile devices - empty headers [website app]

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have a little problem with my integration with Facebook PHP SDK on my website. On desktop everything works fine. When try to register account using fb-login button on mobile devices despite the successful redirection from the facebook website to my website, it receives an empty response.

I don't know where is the main problem, session, redirects policy, cookie problem?
The problem does not exist when accounts are merged and connected - so login function works on mobile, just creating account and connecting new ids.

I note that everything works fine on the desktop version

my config

```
Facebook PHP SDK: 5.6.2
```

Graph API: v14.0

```
$config = array_merge([
        'app_id' => getenv(static::APP_ID_ENV_NAME),
        'app_secret' => getenv(static::APP_SECRET_ENV_NAME),
        'default_graph_version' => static::DEFAULT_GRAPH_VERSION,
        'enable_beta_mode' => false,
        'http_client_handler' => null,
        'persistent_data_handler' => 'memory',
        'pseudo_random_string_generator' => null,
        'url_detection_handler' => null,
    ], $config);
```

**You can see the code implementations below**

```
public function _facebook_account($action = null){

    $isLogged = $this->getCustomer()->isAuthenticated();
    $fb = FacebookAPIHelper::getInstance()->getAPI($this->getContext());
    $redirectUrl = null;

    if (!empty($_POST['secret_code']))
    {
        $code = $_POST['secret_code'];
    }

    if (!$isLogged) {
        if ($action == FacebookAPI::ACTION_LOGIN || $action == FacebookAPI::ACTION_REGISTER){
            $redirectUrl = '/customer/login_with_facebook/' . $action;
        }
    }
    else{
        if ($action == FacebookAPI::ACTION_MERGE) {
            $redirectUrl = '/customer/merge_with_facebook';
        }
        else {
            $this->redirectTo('customer,profile');
        }
    }

    if (!is_null($redirectUrl)) {
        $url = $fb->getLoginUrl($this->getRouter()->getHost(null, true) .  $redirectUrl, isset($code) ? $code : null);
        header("Location: $url");
    }
    else {
        $this->redirectTo('');
    }
}
```

2

```
try {
        $facebookProfileData = FacebookLoginHelper::getFacebookProfileData($this->getContext());
        if ($facebookProfileData) {
            $customer = FacebookLoginHelper::findOrCreateCustomerByFacebookProfileData($facebookProfileData);
        } else {
            $this->addMessageForNextRequest('`facebook_login.error_fetch_user_data`');
            $this->redirectTo('customer,login');
        }

        if (is_null($customer)) {

            $customer = CustomerBase::getCustomerFromFacebookProfileData($facebookProfileData);

            if (Module::moduleInstalled('referer')) {
                if ($this->hasCookie(RefererSettings::COOKIE_NAME)) {
                    $referer = $this->getCookie(RefererSettings::COOKIE_NAME);
                    $customer->referer = $referer;
                }
            }

            $this->view->customer = $customer;
            $this->renderAction('confirm_customer_data.tpl');

        }
```

3

```
public function _login_with_facebook($action)
{
    $customer = null;
    $oldCustomer = $this->getCustomer();
    $isLogged = $oldCustomer->isAuthenticated();
    $facebookLoginNotInstalled = Module::moduleInstalled('facebook_login') == false;

    if ($isLogged) {
        $this->redirectTo('customer,profile');
        return;
    }

    if ($facebookLoginNotInstalled) {
        $this->redirectTo('customer,login');
        return;
    }

    try {
        $facebookProfileData = FacebookLoginHelper::getFacebookProfileData($this->getContext());
        if ($facebookProfileData) {
            $customer = FacebookLoginHelper::findOrCreateCustomerByFacebookProfileData($facebookProfileData);
        } else {
            $this->addMessageForNextRequest('`facebook_login.error_fetch_user_data`');
            $this->redirectTo('customer,login');
        }

        if (is_null($customer)) {

            $customer = CustomerBase::getCustomerFromFacebookProfileData($facebookProfileData);

            if (Module::moduleInstalled('referer')) {
                if ($this->hasCookie(RefererSettings::COOKIE_NAME)) {
                    $referer = $this->getCookie(RefererSettings::COOKIE_NAME);
                    $customer->referer = $referer;
                }
            }

            $this->view->customer = $customer;
            $this->renderAction('confirm_customer_data.tpl');
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: ok, question updated

Comment: Can you please clarify, what _"it receives an empty response in the headers"_ is supposed to mean? What headers are we talking about?

Comment: Before creating account at my website I send users to a specific page where they have to confirm all data get from their fb account. On desktop the form with the data is completed successfully but on mobile devices like iphone or others data is missing and form is empty, lost data like fb id, name, surname, e-mail. I don't know why this method works on desktop not on mobile, where is the difference? In addition login method works fine, so users who connected and created their account on desktop can login sucessfully.